# Blackberry - how to use an older component pack?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am a Blackberry newbie. I develop on Mac OS Lion. I just installed the latest component pack for blackberry. However, the device that I am going to develop for has Blackberry 4.6 installed. So it is unable to run any of the new samples provided by the RIM component pack. How do I obtain an older version on eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install additional BlackBerry SDK versions via the BlackBerry's update site. Follow this guide, [BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse Update Site](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp), to learn how. According to this guide, as for today, the available BlackBerry SDK versions that can be downloaded via the update site are:

- 7.1
- 7.0
- 6.0
- 5.0
- 4.5 (Available for Windows only)

Also check this guide, [BlackBerry Plug-in for Eclipse](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse?os=mac#addUpdateSite).